# Convolution of random variables - confusion about change of variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convolution, change-of-variable

Consider

[image]

I understand everything except of the first line of the note. In particular
$$
\int_\Omega 1_{X(\omega ) + Y (\omega )\in A} \;d \mathbb P(\omega )  =\iint \mathbf{1}_A (x+y) \; \;d(\mu, \nu) (x, y)
$$
I don't quite understand what is $d(\mu,\nu)$. I assume that the author is using the change of variables formula but I can't quite see how are the measures related. In particular, I thought I had to use the change of variables formula
\begin{align*}
\int_{}^{} g \, \mathrm{d}\nu  = \int g \circ  f \, \mathrm{d} \mu .
\end{align*}
where $\nu = \mu (f^{-1})$.

**Question:** Rigorously, how do you justify
$$
\int_\Omega 1_{X(\omega ) + Y (\omega )\in A} \;d \mathbb P(\omega )  =\iint \mathbf{1}_A (x+y) \; \;d(\mu, \nu) (x, y)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the formula (changing the names for the measures, since $X$, $Y$ have laws $\mu$ and $\nu$) $$\int g d\lambda = \int g \circ f d\eta,$$
set $$g(x,y) = 1_A(x+y),$$ $$f(\omega) = (X(\omega), Y(\omega)),$$ $$\eta(S) = \mathbb P(S),$$ for events $S$ and finally $$\lambda(U) = \mathbb P(f^{-1}(U))$$ for measurable $U \subset \mathbb R^2$. Note that when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then this is just the product measure, as  $$\lambda(U_1 \times U_2) = \mathbb P(X \in U_1, Y \in U_2) = \mu(U_1) \times \nu(U_2) $$ which is what the author means by $d(\mu, \nu)$. Once everything is substituted, you get $$\int gdv = \int 1_{A}(x + y) d\lambda = \int 1_{A}(x + y) d(\mu, \nu)$$ and
$$
\int g \circ f d \eta = \int 1_{\{X(\omega) + Y(\omega) \in A\}} d\mathbb P
$$
as desired.

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment. I think I understand now, however, I think you have a typo. On the right hand side of the last line there shouldn't be any omega. In particular, the indicator function should be $1_{\{x,y: X(x)+Y(y) \in A\}}$. Can you double check this? I will then accept your answer.

Comment: Sorry, fixed. It should be right now.

Comment: For completeness:
\begin{align}
f(\omega )= (X(\omega ), Y(\omega )) \in \mathbb{R}^2  \\
g(x, y) = 
\begin{cases}
 1 &  \text{if } x +  y  \in A \\ 
 0 &  \text{otherwise}. 
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, $f: \Omega \to \mathbb R^2$ and $g: \mathbb R^2 \to \{0, 1\}$.